# IE keeps on asking whether to run ActiveX controls or not

Tags: html

when i typed in html like  this

```
var popup = window.open(location.href, "_blank", 
    "menubar=0,location=0,toolbar=0,status=0,directories=0,width=" + 
    screen.width + ",height=" + screen.height);
popup.moveTo(0, 0);
```

inside script language="javascript" and /script

The IE keeps on asking me whether to run active x or not ..plz try executing this to know better.i am unable to explain to u clearly. These codes were provided to me by mr. Amarghosh. i dont wanna always allow my active x .

Comment: See my comment on Amarghosh's answer.

Comment: sorry bobince i forgot to add ur name along with amarghosh

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Mark of the Web` pragmas for this:

```
<!-- saved from url=(0016)http://localhost -->
```

`http://localhost` specifies the Local Intranet zone

```
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
```

`about:internet` specifies the Internet zone

**References**

- [Dude, where’s my intranet zone?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2005/12/07/501075.aspx)
- [The Mark of the Web](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628)